# Facebook SDK and Parse user auth

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, oauth, facebook-ios-sdk

I have setup an application to use Parse.com and the Facebook SDK for user auth.

Is there anyway in Facebook App Center or any where else that I can find the users that setup using Facebook. I can see basic auth information in Parse, but how do I then find the information that is requested from a Facebook user i.e. profile information, email address etc to then email/use?

Thanks